# Custom name for Sum(column) with table as variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have multiple tables with a column on each table called " Balance ", and I'm trying to compute the total of this field using a stored procedure that receives the table as a parameter. But when I run the procedure from the Management studio it gives an error

I want to read the column as TotalBalance from my c# application SqlDataReader class. Here's my procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[fut_getTotalBalance]  --futStudentFees
    @tableName varchar(250)
as
begin 
    select sum(balance) AS TotalBalance from @tableName 
    return
end
```

It's not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The error I get is:

```
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fut_getTotalBalance, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 7]
Must declare the table variable "@tableName".
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

Try this: You have to use dynamic sql to achive this

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[fut_getTotalBalance]  --futStudentFees
    @tableName varchar(250)
    WITH EXECUTE AS 'LimitedUser'
as
begin 
    declare @query varchar(max)
    set @query = 'select sum(balance) AS TotalBalance from '+ QUOTENAME(@tableName)

    exec (@query)
    return
end
```

A *LimitedUser* SQL Server account (which you should create with very limited permissions) improves security by using the [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause.

Comment: There's also no need to give any potential malicious user 250 characters to work with. The dataytpe used to store an objects name is `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`. You're giving the malicious user more capacity than is needed to fulfil the requirement here.

Comment: QUOTENAME() only emits strings up to 128 characters long. So as @Larnu says, the parameter length should be a maximum of 128.

Comment: @RoadWarrior no, `QUOTENAME` returns an `nvarchar(258)`, as per [Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types). If it only returned an `nvarchar(128)` then objects could be truncated.

Comment: @Larnu, my bad! Yet another indication that I shouldn't rely on my (rapidly aging) memory.

Comment: @Larnu, actually it's the input to QUOTENAME that will only receive 128 characters. If you pass more than 128 characters to QUOTENAME you will receive null in return. So my point about the parameter length still stands.

Comment: @RoadWarrior That's what I said. You said `QUOTENAME` "emits" an `nvarchar(128)`, which isn't the case, it's returns a `nvarchar(258)`. The Input parameter, as I define in my intial comment, for `QUOTENAME` is `sysname`.

Comment: @Larnu, my first comment was indeed reinforcing your first comment. It's just that I said "emit" when I should have said "receive".